# Не устанавливается pip

Tags: python, pip

недавно начал изучать Python, надо скачать модуль из pip, а он не открывается, пишет ошибка. Удалил и заново скачал, поставил галочку на PATH, оно все равно не работает.Что делать?

Comment: объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы делаете и какую ошибку вы получаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала убедитесь что у вас установлен pip.ру или pip3.ру. Официальная инструкция как установить pip ( https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html ).

Если pip установлен, то вот короткая инструкция, как установить какой либо пакет:
Рассмотрим на примере пакета numpy. Сначала откройте командую строку с правами администратора (не командная строка питона, а именно вашего ПК). И затем чтобы установить сам пакет используйте команду:

Если вы используете Linux:

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Если вы используете Windows:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Если будет выдавать ошибку, тогда действуйте на прямую. Указывайте свой путь, где у вас хранится ваш pip.

```
C:\Python34\Tools\Scripts\pip3.exe install numpy
```

В итоге вы получите что-то вроде такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это обозначает, что процесс установки пошел.